# SQLAlchemy Query Not Returning Same Value As Database

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project displays research opportunities and lets students signup to participate in them. When registering for a study, the server checks to see if the user is already in another time slot of the same study (not allowed).

The SQLAlchemy code is as follows:

```
same_study = db.session.query(db.func.count(['*'])) \
            .filter(Research.research_id == ResearchSlot.research_id) \
            .filter(ResearchSlot.research_slot_id == StudentResearch.research_slot_id) \
            .filter(StudentResearch.user_id == Users.user_id) \
            .filter(StudentResearch.student_research_id == slot_id) \
            .filter(Users.user_email == user_email) \
            .scalar()
```

In this, slot_id and user_email are variables. When this query runs (and I output the query being run) it looks like this:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Research, ResearchSlot, StudentResearch, Users 
WHERE Research.ResearchID = ResearchSlot.ResearchID 
AND ResearchSlot.ResearchSlotID = StudentResearch.ResearchSlotID 
AND StudentResearch.UserID = Users.UserID 
AND StudentResearch.StudentResearchID = 10
AND Users.UserEmail = "foo@bar.com"
```

The issue is, when the query is executed during use of the website, the query returns 0 (meaning they are not in another instance of the same research study) when it should be returning 1 (because they are in another instance). When I manually execute this query from the MySQL workbench it returns 1 as expected. Why the difference?

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserEmail VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UserPWHash VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UserSalt VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    UserRole BIGINT NOT NULL,
    UserPsychMajor BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    UserPsychMinor BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserRole) REFERENCES Role(RoleID)
);

CREATE TABLE Research (
    ResearchID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ResearchName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ResearchFacilitator BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ResearchDescription VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    ResearchCredits INT NOT NULL,
    IsVisible BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL,
    IsDeleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ResearchID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ResearchFacilitator) REFERENCES Users(UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE ResearchSlot (
    ResearchSlotID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ResearchID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ResearchSlotOpenings INT NOT NULL,
    StartTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    EndTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ResearchSlotID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ResearchID) REFERENCES Research(ResearchID)
);

CREATE TABLE StudentResearch (
    StudentResearchID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ResearchSlotID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    IsCompleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    CreatedOn DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentResearchID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ResearchSlotID) REFERENCES ResearchSlot(ResearchSlotID)
);
```

Comment: Wrong/different DB? You've given very little context to go by...

Comment: It is definitely the same DB, what information would be helpful?

Comment: A minimal self contained example that produces the issue is the ideal. You could/should at least include a stripped down version of your model definitions. A small snippet of example data that should produce the output you want is a must. As it is now it is extremely hard to verify, unless someone spots a clear programming error, but since the query works if you take it to a different environment that seems unlikely.

Comment: Models have been added. I can't produce example data that works because that query does work. It provides the correct data, but only when it is executed from the workbench, not from the code. That is the problem.

Comment: I just tried `func.count()` and `func.count(Research.rearch_id)` and they both still come back with the wrong number when executed in code, but correct from the workbench.

Comment: If you're getting different results for the same query on the same database, then either you're not executing the exact same query or you're not executing them on the same database -- it's as simple as that. So, help us understand: 1. How are you sure you are executing the same query? Are you sure you are not executing some other query before in the same transaction that would affect the result? 2. How are you sure that you're executing them on the same database? Have you tried running `SELECT @@hostname` and `SELECT DATABASE()` in both?

Comment: @univerio 1. I am printing the query being run by sqlalchemy to the console and running it in the workbench. 2. I only have one database. I have not tried either of those, but I will. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I tried the `SELECT @@hostname` and `SELECT Database()` on both and they match.

Comment: @RobRushton This might be completely out there, but have you tried hard coding the values for ```slot_id``` and ```user_email``` to be the same values that you run on the workbench i.e. ```10``` and ```foo@bar.com``` respectively?  Failing that you might considering breaking the query down to simple select from the first table and compare the results from both the app and workbench version.  Then slowly build up and identify where it starts to differ

Comment: @Mr-F I have not hard coded the values in the sqlalchemy query, but I have verified them and their type. I will give hard coding a try.

Comment: @RobRushton sorry I mean try it.  Obviously when you run the query yourself you have to provide some value, so was just suggesting trying that.  I'm hoping that it will show the same results, if so then it would point towards the variables being used not having the values you expect when it is being executed.  It's a long shot, but worth starting somewhere.  Like I said after that, take a look at reducing the overall query down and see where it starts to differ

Comment: @Mr-F That did not solve the problem, but it helped me find where the problem was.

Comment: @RobRushton Glad that you managed to get to the bottom of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a bunch of SQL-related things suggested above, I found out it had nothing to do with the actual statement or information. The problem was with logic in a different part of the server.